# Batch script exclude foldername for winrar

Tags: batch-file, winrar

I want that the script skip all sub folders in a main folder that contains `_Fun_` in the folder name to avoid that winrar archive it.

I tried something but nothing has worked, the last attempt by me looks like:

```
for /D %%F in ("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Pictures\*") do (
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" m -ep1 -mt5 -m1 -v103M -r -x@"_Fun_" "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ArchivePictures\-Archive-Name-" "%%~F"
goto Done
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this batch code to test if name of current folder contains `_Fun_` and skip that folder.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%F in ("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Pictures\*") do (
    set "FolderName=%%~nxF"
    if "!FolderName:_Fun_=!" == "%%~nxF" (
        "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" m -ep1 -mt5 -m1 -v103M -r "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ArchivePictures\-Archive-Name-" "%%~F"
        goto Done
    )
)
:Done
endlocal
```

The name of the folder and the extension (in case of folder contains a dot somewhere) without path is assigned to an environment variable `FolderName`.

In the next line all occurrences of `_Fun_` in environment variable `FolderName` expanded delayed and not already when `cmd.exe` parses entire **FOR** block are replaced by nothing and this string is compared with unmodified folder name.

The string comparison is positive if folder name does not contain `_Fun_` anywhere. In this case the folder is compressed with *WinRAR*.

Read more about string manipulations and delayed environment variable expansion by opening a command prompt window, entering `set /?` or `help set`, executing with key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> and reading the help pages output in console window.

The special character sequences as used here for `%%~nxF` are explained in help of command `call` as well as command `for /?` which can be read by executing `call /?` or `for /?` or `help call` or `help for`.